# Facing the problem upload file in Spring boot project to third-party application

Tags: java, spring-boot

Facing the problem upload file in Spring Boot project to third-party application.
Getting the below error. How to fix this issue? Someone, can you please help me?

```
Matched Data: content-transfer-encoding: binary\r\n","message": "Content-Transfer-Encoding was deprecated by rfc7578 in 2015 and should not be used" message.
Java version :1.8
Springboot : 2.2.0
```

Comment: CAn you add a little more detail? what is the java code you wrote and docs of third party api? sample should be fine

Comment: Take a look at the RFC, [RFC 7578](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578). It says you shouldn't use the Content-Transfer-Encoding header and instead use a part for each file, each part having the same value for the name parameter.